# Angular custom directive for Datepicker, popup issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created a custom directive using angular UI datepicker. 
Angular UI datepicker popup should get opened on button click event. This button click event is getting fired and `is-open` boolean value is being set to true, But the popup is not showing. 
Please advise.

Plunker Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/wszoqlmIzS6h3majJrnN?p=preview

Comment: the datepicker popup shows in your plunker, using Chrome

Comment: but not when pressing the button

Comment: right, got it, the button on the right does not open the popup

Comment: Duplicates- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501725/angular-js-and-bootstrap-ui-date-picker-not-open-in-chrome-on-clicking-on-icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is the event-propagation of the button, which could be prevented by `$event.stopPropagation();`. I already had a [similiar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681001/angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-show-on-button-click-without-function) which could solve your problem.

I have updated the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NTaoqician3yaL69Fd9f?p=preview) which is now working

In the example in the [official documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) you can also find the following lines of code:

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
};
```